# Checking a large set of columns for null-ness

Tags: sql, oracle11g

On my current project (a redesign), I'm tasked with checking whether or not a series of soon-to-be-deleted columns have data, so we can decide if and how we should migrate them into new and improved tables / columns. This task is - per se - not the problem, merely the background.

The problem is, there are about 30 columns to check, out of a total of 150. The table is fairly large so I fear that a chained `select * from table where x is not null or y is not null or...` is a bit..slow.

Is there a better, or more elegant way to check multiple columns for null-ness?

Am I better adviced to just check the columns independetly, or in smaller groups and don't bother with an optimal solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just one table. It will get read record by record (full table scan) and the criteria checked. This is not slow. No sorting, no joining, no sub-selects or intermidiate results. This can't be slow. Don't worry.

BTW: shouldn't that be select * from table where x is not null **OR** y is not null ...?

You want to find all records that contain data in any of the columns, right?